# When trying to share page with Vimeo Video Giving Error

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

I have a page with Vimeo Video [With Vimeo Video](http://allvideolectures.com/v/4iwr2122pX/How-to-use-FireBug-to-modify-a-WordPress-theme) Works perfectly fine
But when i try to share on facebook or some where else it Gives

> IIS 8.0 Detailed Error-500

is it showing because i have added And Image is too Large
        <**meta** property="og:image" content="https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/134160385_1280x720.jpg">

Similar page with YouTube Video works fine [With Youtube Video](http://allvideolectures.com/v/xyTg317794/HTML5-Tutorial-1-Introduction)
Please can anyone Help me on this what could be the Problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When troubleshooting Facebook share problems, you may use this tool:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

I plugged your Vimeo Video url (http://allvideolectures.com/v/4iwr2122pX/How-to-use-FireBug-to-modify-a-WordPress-theme) into there and clicked on the "Fetch new scrape information" button. Then I tried clicking "share" again on your video page and it works now. You may verify if that's the case as well.

I did get this error/similar though for both the Youtube and the Vimeo page:

```
Object at URL 'http://allvideolectures.com/v/xyTg317794/HTML5-Tutorial-1-Introduction' of type 'video.other' is invalid because a required property 'og:video:url' of type 'url' was not provided.
```

Comment: thanks for the answer i think the reason was the page was stored in facebook cache when there was an error, and was showing same for a while when there was no error